# How to merge dbf files in Python or arcpy?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcpy, merge, dbf

I have over one hundred dbf files to merge. Each of files have two columns: `ID` and another field which differs from one file to another.  I want to merge those fields based on `ID` such that each raw corresponds to an unique `ID` containing all merged fields. For example:

```
file 1:
ID FirstName
1  Alan
2  Bell

file 2:
ID LastName
1  R
2  A

merged file:
ID FirstName LastName
1  Alan      R
2  Bell      A
```

**Solution:**

I have a series of files named as 'rawfile200101', 'rawfiles200102',...,'rawfile201104'.  Each of files have two columns: `ID` and another field same as the file name.  I want to merge those fields based on `ID` such that each raw corresponds to an unique `ID` containing all merged fields.

Different from Stata, the "merge" process is called "Join Field" in ArcGIS.  Since I have lots of these files, I will do this in batch.  Take the following as an example

```python
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
env.overwriteOutput = True

yrmn = ['200102', '200103', '200104']

for list in yrmn:
    inFeatures = "I:/rawfile200101.dbf"
    joinField = "VALUE"
    joinTable = "I:/rawfile{}.dbf".format(list)
    fieldList = ["rawfile{}".format(list)]

arcpy.JoinField_management (inFeatures, joinField, joinTable, joinField, fieldList)
```

Comment: This looks like you just need to use [**Join Field**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000065000000) in a manual test.  Would you be able to edit your Question to mention if that solves the test case you describe and, if so, details about where a Python script needs to look to find these and your other hundred files.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, @PolyGeo.  IT WORKS!!! I am very new to python and arcgis.  What I want is called "Merge" in statistics programing like Stata, but "Merge" here is totally different story, which doing things like "Append" in Stata.  Similar confusions have caused lots of troubles to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are calling a Merge appears to be what I would use the **[Join Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000065000000)** tool for because it ...

> Joins the contents of a table to another table based on a common
>   attribute field. The input table is updated to contain the fields from
>   the join table. You can select which fields from the join table will
>   be added to the input table.

Answer (score 2):

you can either iterate using arcpy.da.searchCursor and arcpy.da.insertCursor (easy is you have perfect matching between the ID's) (see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000), or use the built in function arcpy.Addjoin_management (http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000064000000)